# JPA/Hibername orphan removal

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to remove orphan entities when my parent entity no longer referencing the child entities. Here is the my entity sample

```
@CollectionOfElements(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<item> items;
```

I have also tried `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` but no success.

But if I change my annotation to `@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", orphanRemoval=true)` then it is working fine.

Any idea why it is not working with `@CollectionOfElements`

Answer (score 2):

`@CollectionOfElements` is used to map collection of basic types or embeddable objects as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues).
I think this isn't your case, so just use `@OneToMany`.